# How do i remove comma from a JSON value in a JSON string in Redshift table column?

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I have a JSON array which looks like this:

> [{"id":"42832","name":"Santa Ana","Pozos","lat":"None","lon":"None"},{"id":"42834","name":"The Discovery Fund","Cambridge University","lat":"None","lon":"None"}]

I want to remove the comma from the name value "Santa Ana","Pozos" and get the value as "Santa Ana Pozos"; similarly for the other name value as well "The Discovery Fund","Cambridge University" should be "The Discovery Fund Cambridge University".

Tried using replace but not able to correctly point the replace to the comma in the name value.

Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution that will fix all such afflicted lines, or just specifically for this line? I suspect you could simply replace quote-comma-quote (`","`) with comma-space. The better option, of course, would be to fix whatever is producing this file so that it correctly handles commas in data.

Comment: Hello John, I cannot use a simple replace because that would remove all the commas. I am trying to get into a JSON format so I could extract the name value using JSON_extract_path_text in Redshift. This one comma in the name value is causing it to be an invalid JSON and hence I cannot use the function. So please let me know. I want everything to be the same as i mentioned except the comma in the name value.

Comment: Ah, yes! In that case, you cannot do a simple Search & Replace. You will need to parse the line using something more intelligent, such as [Creating a scalar SQL UDF - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html), which can use Python to re-interpret the line. A better solution would be to fix this data _before_ it is loaded into Amazon Redshift.

Comment: isnt there any way using REGEXP_REPLACE to do it?

Comment: No, because the only way to know which quote-comma-quote to replace is to parse the entire line and "understand" the JSON format. Unless, perhaps, you could tell it to look for `,".*",` that is not preceded or followed by a colon, but that's starting to get quite complex.

Comment: Seems like the real solution is to fix whatever generates this bug.

Comment: Well its not a bug, its how the data is coming from the source. So you are saying the source needs to fix this comma issue and then i can use my JSON functions in Redshift.

Comment: Yes, that would be the "correct" solution, rather than doing a lot of work to handle the incorrect data that the source is providing.